# Django_facebook api integration- A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: django, internal-server-error, django-facebook

I am new to django and trying to integrate django_facebook api in my django website that i am currently running on localhost. I am getting an error saying A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.I have attached the error log and other files so that it can help in figuring out the cause of error.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

from . import views

app_name='polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    url(r'^facebook/', include('django_facebook.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django_facebook.auth_urls')),
]
```

**error-log**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/shivani/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/shivani/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 158, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/shivani/newproject/newenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = mw_class()
TypeError: facebook() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
[03/Jan/2016 15:02:41] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

**settings.py**

```
""" Django settings for mysite project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '3qx%oiuq@zyb@f)bnnk3-j4cnt&1p=o#&8bxx5l))wwkn@c!)r'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django_facebook',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
        'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ]

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django_facebook.auth_backends.FacebookBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )


    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_facebook.FacebookCustomUser'

    AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'django_facebook.FacebookProfile'

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
                    'django.core.context_processors.request',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'


    #facebook details

    FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'something'
    FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = 'something'
```

I am unable to figure out the reason of the error.

Comment: Have you created new application here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=web ?

Comment: @inlanger Yes I have already done it.